# Selected option disappears when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a file, template.php, which contains a JS function to add some dropdown box options to the page, so the user can add as many more options as they wish.
My issue is, if the user has selected some options within those select boxes, and then presses the "addsunday" button to add more boxes, the previously chosen options are cleared (so every dropdown on the page resets to 00:00).
I'd like to know what is causing the selections to reset and how I can get around this problem.

```
    $("#addsunday").click(function() {
        var htmlstring = "<div class='shiftwrapper'>";
        htmlstring += "<select data-col-id='start' form='newtemplateform'>";
        htmlstring += "<?php 
                            for($hours=0; $hours<24; $hours++) // the interval for hours is '1'
                                for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30) // the interval for mins is '30'
                                    echo '<option>'.str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':'
                                                    .str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'</option>';?>";
        htmlstring += "</select>"; 
        htmlstring += "<select data-col-id='finish' form='newtemplateform'>";
        htmlstring += "<?php 
                            for($hours=0; $hours<24; $hours++) // the interval for hours is '1'
                                for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30) // the interval for mins is '30'
                                    echo '<option>'.str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':'
                                                    .str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'</option>';?>";
        htmlstring += "</select>";
        htmlstring += "<select data-col-id='loc' form='newtemplateform'>";
        htmlstring += "<?php foreach($locations as $location){ print '<option value=\"$location\">' . $location . '</option>\n'; }?>";
        htmlstring += "</select>";
        htmlstring += "<button class='removeshift'>Remove Shift</button><br/>";
        htmlstring += "</div>";
        document.getElementById('sundaywrap').innerHTML += htmlstring;
        console.log("Sunday clicked");

    });
```

I apologise if this is a really inefficient way to repeat code, I'm still learning.
Here's a really bad fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L7npxvzp/
It doesn't work however you can see the structure of how the dropdowns work. There's a button to add more dropdowns, it is when this button is pressed that the previously changed selections reset back to their defaults.

Comment: why are you mixing HTML and PHP in your javascript string?

Comment: Because I have no idea what I'm doing, I just piece together what I can find.

Comment: You can't use PHP in jsfiddle. You need to replace that part with the output of the PHP script.

Comment: @Barmar  you can't use PHP inside javascript at all!

Comment: @low_rents True, but you can output Javascript from a PHP script, and use PHP loops to create some of the JS.

Comment: @Barmar yes, you can also view a PDF file on your iPhone but that's not what OP is talking about in her question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
    document.getElementById('sundaywrap').innerHTML += htmlstring;
```

This replaces the DOM elements in `#sundaywrap` with new DOM elements that come from parsing the HTML after you've concatenated `htmlstring`. Any dynamic state in the old DOM elements, such as selected items from a menu, is lost.

Instead of concatenating to the HTML, you should append to the DOM:

```
$("#sundaywrap").append(htmlstring);
```

Comment: Amazing thank you!! Fixed and works perfectly. Much appreciated.